# gdalwarp() does not work to reproject OMI/Aura TOMS-Like Ozone data

Tags: raster, r, gdalwarp, hdf, hdf5

I'm trying to convert the OMI/Aura TOMS-Like Ozone data provided in HDF5 to the GeoTIFF format using gdal_translate() in the R environment. gdal_translate() provided this unknown Extention.
[image: OMI/Aura TOMS-Like Ozone]

so I want to reproject the ozone data and using gdalwarp(), thereby I got error like this- G:/O3_Data/O3_L3_global_rjhiheproject.tif: No such file or directory (GDAL error 4)

```
My code-
    library(gdalUtilities)
    library(gdalUtils)
    library(raster)
    library(sf)
    library(terra)


    fname = 'G:/O3_Data/OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2010m0601_v003-2012m0409t160627.he5'
    gdalinfo(fname)
    sds <- get_subdatasets(fname)
    sds
    gdalUtils::gdal_translate(sds[1], dst_dataset = "G:/O3_Data/O3_L3_global_2.tif",format="GTiff")


    #####  "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"
    # -------- The gdalwarp utility is an image mosaicing, reprojection and warping utility.

    gdalUtils::gdalwarp("G:/O3_Data/O3_L3_global_2.tif",dstfile="G:/O3_Data/O3_L3_global_rjhiheproject.tif",
                t_srs="EPSG:3410",output_Raster=TRUE,
                overwrite=TRUE,verbose=TRUE)


    rastt <- raster("G:/O3_Data/O3_L3_global_2.tif")
    plot(rastt)
    extent(rastt)
    crs(rastt)
```

An example of the HDF5 file can be [download here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S1-hznoZkVfa6RXhbQiV2043j2m_-CKu/view?usp=sharing)